# how to display Json Formated Datetime in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, json

how to display Json datetime formate in angularJs its showing Datetime as"/Date(820434600000)/"

**Angular Code**

```
app.controller("MyDeptCntrl", function ($scope, MyDeptSer) {
    $scope.BtnDept = function () {
          var Dept = MyDeptSer.GetDeptData();
        Dept.then(function (d) {
            $scope.DeptData = d.data;
          //  $filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
        },function(e){
            alert('Loading Failed....')
        })
    }
```

Comment: try;  var date = new Date(jsonDate)

Answer (score 0):

use below function to parse the date first

```
function dateParser(input){
    input = input.replace('/Date(', '');
    return new Date(parseInt(input,10));
}
```

so

```
    $scope.DeptData = dateParser(d.data);
```

Comment: app.controller("MyDeptCntrl", function ($scope, MyDeptSer) {
    $scope.BtnDept = function () {
          var Dept = MyDeptSer.GetDeptData();
        Dept.then(function (d) {
            function dateParser(input) {
                input = input.replace('/Date(', '');
                return new Date(parseInt(input, 10));
                $scope.DeptData = d.data;

            }
    
        },function(e){
            alert('Loading Failed....')
        })
    }  even not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
convertJsonDateTimeToJs: function (jsonDate) {
    var dateSlice = jsonDate.slice(6, 24);
    var milliseconds = parseInt(dateSlice);
    return new Date(milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: wher i mentioned this query im getting error at convertJsonDateTimeToJs

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend changing your server side code to use a friendlier JSON serializer but if not, try:

```
// You start with /Date(820434600000)/
// substr(6) takes off the /Date( part and pass the number 820434600000 into the parseInt function.  
// Note: the parseInt function will ignore the )/ and the end.
var friendlyDate = new Date(parseInt($scope.DeptData.someDateMember.substr(6)));

// Then, you can format it using angular date filter -- for example:
$scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')(friendlyDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```